# is there any way to change an element in a list made out of lines of a file?

Tags: python, list, file

I have a list of books which are written in a file(each book is a separate line, and it has multiple attributes divided by `,` and also has True or False as the last attribute), and after writing it to a list using

```
list_of_books = open('books'.txt').read().split()
```

i have to change True to False or vice versa, 
is there any way to do that?

example of the list

```
['qwe,rty,1999,1231231231234,Drama,1000,1,True',
 'rty,asd,1900,2342342342345,Fantasy,1000,4,True', 
 'tui,fgh,2009,4564564564567,Horror,900,5,True']
```

Comment: are you trying to change the data in the file ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that. It's actually quite simple FWIW, I would even dare to say "trivial". What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: Hint: use `split(',')` to turn each string into it's own list inside the bigger list

Comment: Consider using the `csv` module to read your file. Updating the list is one (easy) thing; reflecting those changes to the original file is another.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
itertools

inverse ={"True":"False", "False":"True"}

with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    for *row,b in csv.reader(infile):
        outfile.write(itertools.chain(row, [inverse[b]]))
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the Boolean will *always* be at the end, then you could simply change what the string says like this:

```
exampleList = ['qwe,rty,1999,1231231231234,Drama,1000,1,True',
               'rty,asd,1900,2342342342345,Fantasy,1000,4,True', 
               'tui,fgh,2009,4564564564567,Horror,900,5,True']

#Change the second element in the list from True to False
listElement = exampleList[1]
exampleList[1] = listElement[:-4] + "False"

print(exampleList)
```

Or, you could use split() to do it

```
exampleList = ['qwe,rty,1999,1231231231234,Drama,1000,1,True',
               'rty,asd,1900,2342342342345,Fantasy,1000,4,True', 
               'tui,fgh,2009,4564564564567,Horror,900,5,True']

listElement = exampleList[1].split(",")
listElement[-1] = "False"
exampleList[1] = listElement

print(exampleList)
```

Comment: That seems needlessly brittle; what's wrong with parsing the inputs?

Comment: It is a simple way to do it is all.

Comment: Simple, but needlessly brittle. There are other more robust solutions that don't involve arbitrary string slicing. If the last 4 characters turn out to not be `True` you still replace them rather than fail.